# Error when use anything(); in Android testing incompatible types required: Matcher <View> found: Matcher <Object>

Tags: android, testing, android-testing, android-espresso

I run the code belows and got error at   return anything();

```
error: incompatible types
required: Matcher <View>
found:    Matcher <Object>

/** 
     * Perform action of waiting until UI thread is free. <p/> E.g.: onView(isRoot()).perform(waitUntilIdle());
     * @return
     */
    public static ViewAction waitUntilIdle(){
      return new ViewAction(){
        @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints(){
          return anything();
        }
        @Override public String getDescription(){
          return "wait until UI thread is free";
        }
        @Override public void perform(    final UiController uiController,    final View view){
          uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
        }
      }
    ;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Typecast Matcher<Object> like `return (Matcher<View> )anything()`.

Comment: Already tried got error inconvertable types, cannot convert

Comment: Error:(234, 37) error: inconvertible types
required: Matcher<View>
found:    Matcher<Object>

Comment: I am assuming that Matcher<?> is a data structure. So the simplest solution you can try is iterate over all the the items in Matcher<Object> and put them in another Matcher<View> and return that Matcher<View>.

`Matcher<View> temp = new Matcher();
for(Object view : Matcher<Object>)
     temp.add((View)view);

return temp;
`

Comment: I understand your idea, but it cannot iterate that way. I also dont know how to do that.

Comment: What is Matcher<?> ? What does it extends from?

Comment: package org.hamcrest;
public interface Matcher<T> extends SelfDescribing

Comment: I don;t know what is `SelfDescribing`. What I am asking is, is Matcher<?> an ArrayList, a hashmap, a set?

Comment: Sorry I think it's not an ArrayList, a hashmap, a set

Comment: Provide the implementation for anything().

Comment: seach for anything(); in https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/5f79ba7f0c15871f02a95c622c954eefedfcf183/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.java

Comment: try return (Matcher<View>)anything().newInstance()

Comment: Thank you for your help, but cannot use .newInstance()  with error cannot resolved method newInstance()

Comment: Report back your solution if you find one.

Comment: Sure @UmerFarooq, btw our name is a bit similar Um, Umer  :)

Comment: are you getting a compile time error?

Comment: @UmerFarooq the answer is here, it's work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`anything()` is not a generic method, so you will always get a `Matcher<Object>`.

Internally `anything()` uses the `IsAnything` class. You can make your own `anyView()` method to return a `Matcher<View>`.

```
public static ViewAction waitUntilIdle(){
    return new ViewAction(){
        @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints(){
            return anyView();
        }

        @NonNull
        private Matcher<View> anyView() {
            return new IsAnything<>();
        }

        @Override public String getDescription(){
            return "wait until UI thread is free";
        }
        @Override public void perform(    final UiController uiController,    final View view){
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
        }
    }
            ;
}
```